# find element in new opened tab selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium

How to find element in new opened tab selenium c#, here is code to open new tab and switch to it:

```
new Actions(driver)
    .KeyDown(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control)
    .Click(NewPost)
    .KeyUp(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control)
    .Perform();
                                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                                //driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());

                          ReadOnlyCollection<string> tabs = driver.WindowHandles;
                            driver.SwitchTo().Window(tabs[1]);
```

how find element in new tab, for example tabs[1], Thanks for help

Comment: why is the code so badly formatted? ... have you not looked at your own post?

Comment: You do regular search.

Comment: i  do regular search but i did not find , if you know the way please tell me, because i realty search and not found example to access elements in new opened tabs